# Spatio-temporal Kriging and how extract specific values

Tags: r, interpolation, kriging

I have several years of data that needs to be converted to STDFDF.
Shapiro.test and Adf.test talk about non-stationarity and non-normal distribution.

```
particolato_May2021 <- read.delim(file = "Data.txt")
dput(particolato_May2021) ##sample data

##set the stations of the region
stations <- read.csv("stations_CS.csv", header=TRUE)
names(stations)
coord <-cbind(stations$Longitude,stations$Latitude)
plot(coord)
save(stations,file='data/stations.Rdata')

coords <- SpatialPoints(particolato_May2021[, c("Longitude", "Latitude")]) 
summary(coords)
particolato_sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, particolato_May2021) 
names(particolato_sp)
is(particolato_sp)

particolato_May2021$Data <- as.POSIXct(particolato_sp$Data, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
save(particolato_May2021,file='data/particolato.Rdata')

##The problem starts here
STFDF_day <- stConstruct(particolato,space=c('Longitude','Latitude'),time='Data',
                         SpatialObj=SpatialPoints(particolato[,c('Longitude','Latitude')]))
is(STFDF_day)
proj4string(STFDF_day) <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
save(STFDF_day,file='data/STFDF_day.Rdata')
load('data/STFDF_day.Rdata') 

#Variogram
var <- variogramST(PM10~1,data=STFDF_day,tunit="days",
                   assumeRegular=F,na.omit=T)
```

This is an incomplete data set for seven years, and I replaced the missing data with averages for the same days in previous years. I want to conduct space-time kriging and extract data for other unknown points (long, lat) before kriging for the same period for each day.
I have following problem:

```
Found more than one class "xts" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'spacetime'
Also defined by ‘quantmod’
Error in `vectbl_as_row_location()`:
! Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript `time` must be a simple vector, not a matrix.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

**Sample date**

```
 structure(list(NetC = c("Cosenza Provincia", "Cosenza Provincia", 
"Cosenza Provincia", "Reti Private", "Reti Private"), Stat = c("Citta dei Ragazzi", 
"Rende", "Acri", "Firmo", "Schiavonea"), ID = c("IT1938A", "IT2086A", 
"IT2110A", "IT1766A", "IT2090A"), Longitude = c(16.2452, 16.2433, 
16.3868, 16.194, 16.5468), Latitude = c(39.3134, 39.3389, 39.4896, 
39.7138, 39.6518), Data = structure(c(1619820000, 1619820000, 
1619820000, 1619820000, 1619820000), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), PM10 = c(28.48, 29.31, 32.3, 103.06, 19.83), day = c("01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01"), month = c("05", "05", "05", "05", "05"
), year = c("2021", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021"), avePM10 = c(17.53875, 
20.6028571428571, 19.4285714285714, 29.46625, 18.7257142857143
), comment = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

*Stations:*

```
structure(list(Location = c("IT1766A", "IT1938A", "IT2086A", 
"IT2090A", "IT2110A"), Longitude = c(16.19397, 16.24517, 16.24334, 
16.54677, 16.3868), Latitude = c(39.71376, 39.3134, 39.33893, 
39.65176, 39.48963), station_type = c("Industrial", "Background", 
"Traffic", "Industrial", "Background"), station_area = c("Rural", 
"Urban", "Urban", "Rural", "Urban")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. You create `df`, and then save it to a file, and then read back *from a different file name*. I've tried writing it and reading back from the same file, but then the next line fails because the dates are "2021-06-26" but you try and convert them with `format = "%m/%d/%Y"` so I get NA for all the dates after that. Which makes me think maybe you are reading them from a different file. I'm not sure even why you take the data on this round trip via a file when you should be able to work with `df` directly.

Comment: `Error in vectbl_as_row_location():
! Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript time must be a simple vector, not a matrix.
---
Backtrace:
  1. spacetime::stConstruct(...)
 14. rlang::cnd_signal(x)`

Comment: Can you edit your question to a) remove the statistical tests at the start which don't seem relevant, b) cut out all code after the line that generates the error message, c) make the code so it can be run by cut and paste, which might just mean replacing your read.delim with "with DATA as the sample data below...". The more compact you can make your question the easier it is to see where the problem is and the more likely people are to try and fix it. A long listing followed by "and I get this error" is not helpful to us.

Comment: Spacedman, thank you for your understanding. I remove the statistical tests and the initial part about replacing NA data.

Comment: The line after `##The problem starts here` references an object called `particolato` - `stConstruct(particolato,space=` but you don't show what this object is. This is why you have to make sure your code runs when cut and pasted into a clean R session, otherwise we can't help because we don't know what objects you have and how you are getting the error you are seeing. Start from reading your sample data and stations, and work through to the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a `STFDF` object then use the `STFDF` function. Your data must have n x m rows where n is the number of spatial locations and m is the number of time points. m=1 seems to be invalid so I can't illustrate this with your sample data but I'll extend it for an example.

The data must also be *sorted* into space-time order, so all the data for the first time point, then all the data for the second time point, and so on until you have n x m rows.

Starting with `pts` as your sample data, I'll first convert to a plain data frame because it seems to be a `tbl_df` and this is incompatible with real data frames - avoid as much as you can.

```
pts = structure(....
pts = as.data.frame(pts)
```

Since this is only one point I'll duplicate it a couple of times to 15 rows and set the times of points 6-10 and 11-15 to 1 day and 2 days past the first five data points which are all at the same time point:

```
pts = rbind(pts, pts, pts)
pts$Data[6:10] = pts$Data[1:5] + 24*60*60 # add one day
pts$Data[11:15] = pts$Data[1:5] + 2*24*60*60
```

I'll also jitter the measure variable a bit too so the data values aren't repeated so we can see what's happening. Don't do this on your real data of course...

pts$PM10 = pts$PM10 + rnorm(15, 0, 2)

Now we can work out the "grid" points in space and time:

```
n = 5
T = unique(pts$Data)
S = SpatialPoints(pts[1:n,c("Longitude","Latitude")])
```

And you can confirm there are 3 time points and 5 space points, and we know they are ordered correctly. The first 5 rows are day 1, the next are day 2, the last day 3, and the locations are always in the same order. Your data must be in this format.

Now all is set up to make a STFDF:

```
pts.st = STFDF(S, T, pts)
```

which we can check and plot:

```
> class(pts.st)
[1] "STFDF"
attr(,"package")
[1] "spacetime"
> stplot(pts.st[,,"PM10"])
```

[image]

Comment: I am having problems using STFDF. stConstruct() creates STIDF object.

Comment: I've rewritten to use STFDF rather than stConstruct.

Comment: I do this code 
`pts = as.data.frame(pts)
n = unique(pts$ID)
T = unique(pts$Data)
S = SpatialPoints(pts[1:n,c("Longitude","Latitude")])`
And have this error
`Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'obj' in selecting a method for function 'coordinates': NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In 1:n : numerical expression has 5 elements: only the first used
2: In `[.data.frame`(pts, 1:n, c("Longitude", "Latitude")) :
  NAs introduced by coercion`